# Is Ethan Woods using sane binary code to send chessboard message?

Tags: computers, extant

In season two episode 11 of *Extant*, Ethan is using a chess board to send a message by pressing white and black squares. He say he is using black squares for 1 and white for 0.

Is the code *real*?

- Sequence: 1001000110100100011011
- His mother, Molly, say the message says "Hi".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, it is real code. The sequence 1001000110100100011011 matches up to [7-bit ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) “*`Hi<CR>`*” + a [parity bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) if one use *even parity*-scheme.

```
bin      dec   hex  ASCII
1001000   72  0x48      H
1101001  105  0x69      i
0001101   13  0x0d     CR
1        parity bit: total 9 bits set, set parity bit to 1 to make it even.
```

`CR` is [Carriage-Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and used to denote something like *“end of text”* in this case.

Now, that is the kind of detail we like.

[image: USASCII]